# Ajuda em consulta SQL para LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

estou com um problema/dificuldade, tenho essa seguinte consulta SQL que preciso transformar-la em LINQ, porém estou tendo problemas no COUNT() do LINQ.

```
select m.id_marca, m.ds_marca, pm.ds_caracterist_tecnica_prdmca, count(fp.id_fornec_prod_marca_fpmarcot) as t from Produto_Marca pm

left join Fornecedor_Prod_Marca_Cotacao fp  on fp.id_produto_marca_prdmca = pm.id_produto_marca_prdmca

join Marca m on pm.id_marca = m.id_marca

where pm.id_produto_prod = 98
group by m.id_marca, m.ds_marca, pm.ds_caracterist_tecnica_prdmca
order by t desc
```

segue código LINQ

```
var x = from a in produtoMarcaService.GetAll()
                    join b in FornecedorProdMarcaCotacaoService.GetAll() on a.IdProdutoMarca equals b.IdProdutoMarca into juncao
                    from c in juncao.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join d in MarcaService.GetAll() on a.IdMarca equals d.IdMarca
                    where a.IdProduto == id
                    group c by new { d.DsMarca, d.IdMarca, a.CdProdutoMarca, a.DsCaracteristTecnica, a.DsComercialProduto } into f
                    select new
                    {
                        f.Key.DsMarca,
                        f.Key.IdMarca,
                        f.Key.CdProdutoMarca,
                        f.Key.DsCaracteristTecnica,
                        f.Key.DsComercialProduto,
                        Count = f.Count()
                    };
```

Tem alguma forma de deixar igual ao do SQL?

Pelo linq o count deixa todos que estão zerados com o número 1, Print:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já com o meu count pelo SQL todos que estão zerados, ficam realmente zerados, PRINT:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a solução fazendo o seguinte, o count antes do group by.

```
var Ofertas = from a in produtoMarcaService.GetAll()
                        join b in FornecedorProdMarcaCotacaoService.GetAll() on a.IdProdutoMarca equals b.IdProdutoMarca into juncao
                            from c in juncao.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join d in MarcaService.GetAll() on a.IdMarca equals d.IdMarca
                    where a.IdProduto == id && a.DtDesativacao == null
                    let Count = juncao.Count()
                    group c by new { d.DsMarca, d.IdMarca, a.CdProdutoMarca, a.DsCaracteristTecnica, a.DsComercialProduto , Count} into f
                    select new
                    {
                        f.Key.DsMarca,
                        f.Key.IdMarca,
                        f.Key.CdProdutoMarca,
                        f.Key.DsCaracteristTecnica,
                        f.Key.DsComercialProduto,
                        f.Key.Count
                    };
```

Comment: Achei essa solução porém existe alguma maneira de aprimorar? falo em questão de desempenho.

Comment: Geralmente uso dapper nessas querys de consultas/relatórios para melhorar o desempenho. Mas pra sua pergunta especificamente pra LINQ não vejo oque melhorar.